# translate paginatorTemplate

Tags: jsf, primefaces, translation

I'm using paginatorTemplate on my p:datatable (Primefaces1 I know, old, but legacy code)

```
paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}  #{msg.all_lists_numberOfRowsDisplayed_label}{RowsPerPageDropdown}">
```

On screen I get

```
 << first < prev 12 next > last >> Number of Rows:
```

Is it possible to translate the "first" "prev" "next" and "last" labels?

Comment: how bout changing the generated html with jquery , like `jQuery("someIDAndClassSelectorIGuess").html("firstLocalized");` ?

Comment: That would be a 'crappy' solution :) But if there is no other... then crappy solutions will do.

Comment: Yup... In pf 3+ there are no labels , only arrows :)

Comment: I know. I wonder how in PF3 I could change them to labels and have them translate properly?

Comment: Problem with using jquery or javascript is that I must call the same script on every page with a table. And evreytime you trigger something on paginator. (the link to first page doens't exist on opage load. It is just a label. But when you change page this becomes a link = other field )

Comment: Well... It was just an idea... I guess you need to find a proper hook , for example call this js function on every pagination event or on page load etc...